# Javascript regex to separate words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with words separated by spaces. I am using a regex to separate the words into an array. Since words can also be contractions like `I'm` so I had to alter my regex and also look for single quote as well. The words are still separated fine but the word with contraction is including an extra slash `\`.

My code:

```
function separate(str) {
  var myRegex = /[a-z0-9']+/gi;
  var words = str.match(myRegex);
  console.log(words);
}

separate("I'm a little tea pot");
```

console.log(words) gives `[ 'I\'m', 'a', 'little', 'tea', 'pot' ]`

As it can be seen, the 1st word should be `I'm` but I am getting `I\'m`.
Why I am getting this slash and how can I remove it by changing regex?

Comment: The backslash in `'I\'m'` is not a literal one, it is there to show you that the single quote of the contraction is a literal one, and not the separator for the string.  That is, that backslash is not "really" there.

Comment: Oh totally missed that, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you give full string which you wanted to check?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to remove backslash from string,

```
string.replace(/\\/g, "");
```

Comment: Like @Tim Biegeleisen pointed out, the slash is just used to escape the single quote and its not really there, so no need to try and remove it

Answer (score 0):

So my output was correct but I wasn't seeing it correct. What I mean by that is since, I was printing the array so since elements of array were strings so javascript was displaying them as strings with single quotes like `['one','two']`. My 1st string in array had a single quote in it so javascript was just escaping it with a `\` like `'I'm'`.

I should have just printed `words[0]` to clear the confusion.